# Symfony 2.1 controller overwrite in kernel.request results "Allowed memory size exhausted"

Tags: symfony, event-listener

Greetings there coders,

I try to create a request route based controller overwrite feature as a kernel.request listener by the following way:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event){

    $requested_uri = $event->getRequest()->getRequestUri();

    if($requested_uri == '/' || $requested_uri == '/index.php' || $requested_uri == '/index_dev.php'){
        $event->getRequest()->attributes->set('_controller', 'TestHomeBundle:Home:index');
    }   
}
```

However it shows the following error in the apache log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 39 bytes) in /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Generator/UrlGenerlGenerator.php on line 182
```

I registered it in the following way.

```
 kernel.listener.homepage_rewrite_listener:
    class: Test\HomeBundle\EventListener\HomepageRewriteListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest, priority: 35 }
```

The main problem is that I cannot give this more memory. Any Ideas are welcome. Thank you in advance.